# Was the year 2000 a really peaceful time in history for the West?

Tags: western-civilisation, 21st-century

In the year 2000 I seem to remember that the world seemed mostly at peace (in the Western World at least). The worst thing was the fear of the millennial bug or that some unknown cult might try something weird - which they didn't.

In the UK, there seemed to be peace in Northern Ireland after many decades.

The Balkan conflicts had settled down.

Islamic Terrorism hadn't yet had a proven it was a direct threat to western countries. It was pre-9/11.

Social media hadn't really got going. This was before YouTube/Twitter/Facebook. I mention this only that social media has [enabled many uprisings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_media_and_the_Arab_Spring), some of which were violently countered, as well as [allowing many terrorists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrorism_and_social_media), and insurgents to gain recruits from all over the world in recent years. As well as pumping out propaganda to [inspire lone wolf attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boston_Marathon_bombing#Backgrounds).

So was the dawn of this century really a peaceful time?

Comment: What research have you done? what does social media have to do with peace?What [research have you done](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wars_1990%E2%80%932002).  I think that unless revised, this question is likely to be closed as either unclear what you're asking or opinion based.  Before you assert that [Islamic Terrorism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_terrorism) hadn't started, check the attack on the [Marine barracks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1983_Beirut_barracks_bombings), or the first attempted bombing of the towers, or....

Comment: The question is obviously too subjective to be answered here, but I love the mention of social media on a par with wars and terrorism.

Comment: Putting aside my snark, I would advise you to either remove mention of social media and make some effort to document how you measure "peaceful".  The world has been growing more peaceful over time, and that trend has accelerated in the recent era (? Piinker? Can't remember the name of that hypothesis). And please edit to remove offense.  It is kind of hurtful to compare a tweetwar with the attacks on the Marine barracks.

Comment: @Evargalo. Yes, ISIS recruited lots of foreign fighters using social media such as Facebook. The Arab Spring which caused chaos in North Africa was helped by Twitter. Social Media also helped the migrants from North Africa and Syria get to Europe along with many terrorists. The sexual attacks in Cologne were probably organised via social media. The recent fires in Sweden were no doubt organised on social media. ISIS spread their terrorist videos via social media. So, yes, social media does have a big role to play. Before social media hardly any of those things would have happened.

Comment: What has your research shown so far?

Comment: @Aaron this is my research.

Comment: Jokes aside, a carefully written question about the consequences of social medias on peace might be interesting, but there were revolutions, refugees, gang rapes, arson and terrorism propaganda long before them. I don't agree with your claim about the Arab spring but that's not the place to debate it.

Comment: I've undeleted my comments - I realize that my attitude is less pleasant than I want to be, but I find it difficult to remain silent when people erase the Marine barracks from history equate mean tweets with dying people. Please read [help] and consult Wikipedia and google before you ask here.

Comment: @LangLangC It was absolutely Islamic, if not Islamist per Salafi/Wahabist.  That the Iranian/Persian influence in that area and at that time is blissfully ignored, as was their attempt at leadership in a larger Islamic Revolution than they had just had, is part of the problem with a lot of revisionist history in this century.

Comment: @LangLangC Yes, it was.  It was very much framed in religious terms, although at the time a lot of the blame and finger pointing went to "Shiite's" as "the bad guy" ... because Reagan had taken sides in Lebanon's civil war (which was multi sided).  Shiite groups in Lebanon, to include the freshly formed Hezbollah, were directly tied to the Islamic Revolution (as led by Iran)  by both money and belief.  It's been a while, but the Druze had their own ax to grind, but often got lumped in with "those bad guys."  It was a mess.

Comment: @LangLangC Yeah, in chat, though I think we have sort of beaten this horse into glue. :)

Comment: I'm feeling kinda bad for poor Zooby here. I'd be with you all against a question that asserted terrorism was invented in 2001, or Twitter causes genocide, but that just isn't this question. I've edited a bit, including adding a more balanced view of the generally-acknowledged role of social media.

Comment: @T.E.D. & OP: Find a quote like "2000 was really peaceful, in comparison" and define what is "World/West" as well as "peace(-ful)". As I wrote before: "War" as a reference point might be unsuitable as politics moved beyond the very word, "those labeled terrorist" might have never used it or even declare it unheard. Is this comparing 'personal memory', 'Western narrative' at the time/now or contentious analysis now? Reporting, perception, attention, historical narrative, perspective… Now its POB, & a bit unclear to me. With research and definitions it might be great from the start.

Comment: @LangLangC - There are in fact people who try to quantify these things (mostly in hopes of giving us sold numbers to work on improving, I believe). Its not super difficult to go to them for data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [near as I can tell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wars_1990%E2%80%932002), the only western country (for some definitions of "western") that was directly involved in a war in early 2001 was Russia in the [Second Chechen War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Chechen_War).

Israel, if you count them, was dealing with the [Second Intifada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Intifada). Roughly on that level there was an ethnic Albanian [insurgency in Macedonia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2001_insurgency_in_the_Republic_of_Macedonia).

That is certainly a low ebb. The [number of conflicts per year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_number_of_conflicts_per_year) has been more or less on the rise since, with a particular spike up in 2012.